# BigQuery Node library retries for which error codes

Tags: google-bigquery

As per documentation if we pass `autoRetry=true` while initializing **BigQuery Node client** then the Node library Automatically retry requests if the response is related to rate limits or certain intermittent server errors.

I would like to know for which exact http codes and error codes this retry will take place. e.g. 429 or ESOCKETTIMEDOUT etc ?  Nothing is mentioned specifically about these retry able error codes in official error [document](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/error-messages)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The **GCP SDKs** basically use the **GCP APIs** behind the scenes. Between the **API** and the **SDK** there is a **common layer** for all the GCP products. You can find how the retry is handled by this common layer in the code below. This code comes from this [GitHub](https://github.com/googleapis/nodejs-common/blob/dbaad170a2e3a6785568523086f15d88fb34eaca/src/util.ts#L513-L536) file.

```
  shouldRetryRequest(err?: ApiError) {
    if (err) {
      if ([408, 429, 500, 502, 503].indexOf(err.code!) !== -1) {
        return true;
      }

      if (err.errors) {
        for (const e of err.errors) {
          const reason = e.reason;
          if (reason === 'rateLimitExceeded') {
            return true;
          }
          if (reason === 'userRateLimitExceeded') {
            return true;
          }
          if (reason && reason.includes('EAI_AGAIN')) {
            return true;
          }
        }
      }
    }

    return false;
  }
```

With that we can conclude that the client re-tries when the code is **408**, **429**, **500**, **502**, **503** or when the reason of error is **rateLimitExceeded**, **userRateLimitExceeded** or **EAI_AGAIN**

Comment: rmesteves, any idea what is timeout value for each retry ? I see '60000' ms in variable  requestDefaults in same code, is it the right timeout value ?

Comment: @Rajjy yes, the requestDefaults is used to configure the request in the makeRequest function